# It is possible to assign array 'value key' to a value?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
var list =['lemon', 'apple'];
list['yuck'] = 'durian';

list.forEach(function(i){
    console.log(i);
});
```

The out put is

```
lemon
apple
```

So where is durian?

This question is not about how use array properly, I just find it odd that we able to do that, what's really going on here?

Comment: Your adding a property  `yuck` to the array. Not adding a new index. `forEach` only iterates the arrays indexes. Index's can only be integers greater than zero. There are a few other rules too like max size and the relationship between them and the `length` property.

Comment: You would have to do `list.push("durian");` for it to work.

Comment: Too bad the good answer in the linked QA isn't accepted. There's still no point in not closing this one.

Comment: this is a perfectly valid question and doesnt need the down votes

Comment: @OliverWatkins I agree downvotes aren't necessary. It needs a close vote though as it's a duplicate.

Comment: i would say they are similar but not the same. This question is more succinct and should replace the older question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`forEach` iterates on an array's elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), that is the properties identified by a positive integer. `'yuck'` is a string which can't be converted to an integer.

If you really want to iterate on all values, you can do this:

```
for (var key in list) {
  console.log(list[key]);
}
```

But it breaks all the optimizations of arrays. You should probably use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) or an object instead.

Comment: I checked out set, it's not full supported yet at this moment.

Comment: If the browser you're targeting don't support it, then use a simple object instead of an array. Or use push to add elements.

Comment: can you please elaborate why it breaks optimization?

Comment: Array manipulation are very fast in moderne JS engines when the array is used in an expected way. You can see an introduction to this problem here: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers (with exemples less basic than just making an array not an array)

Answer (score 2):

Because that's not how you add a value to a javascript array. You have to use the method `Array.prototype.push()`

```
var list = ['lemon', 'apple'];
list.push('durian');

list.forEach(function(i){
    console.log(i);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`list['yuck'] = 'durian';`

Here the syntax says add the text `durain` to a property  `yuck`.

Here you are adding key values. This is how you assign values to a object.

The above line will throw an exception as you cannot add key values to array. So your array is never modified.

And this one

`list.forEach(function(i){
    console.log(i);
});`

You are looping the initial array. Hence same values are printed.

On other hand you can use.
 `list.push('durian')`

Or

`list[2] = 'durian'`